# Uso de UUID como identificador de documentos e consulta pública pode ser considerado um caso de uso cabível?

Tags: uuid

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto de nível acadêmico. O sistema consiste na criação de documentos pelo usuário. Esse documento é registrado para que o usuário possa vê-lo/imprimi-lo sempre que quiser, mas também, pessoas podem consultar tal documento desde que o proprietário lhe passe o identificador. Então, a pessoa pode digitar o identificador no sistema e visualizar o documento. Seria adequado registrar os documentos no banco de dados com uso de UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) e esse identificador servir como código de consulta, ou seja, o dono do documento pode compartilhar passando, por exemplo, `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000`, para que uma pessoa possa ter acesso ao documento. Eu sei que o UUID é uma boa alternativa para ser usada como chave identificadora de entidades em banco de dados, mas para usar como referência externo se aplica? Se não, alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: Sim, e não, depende. A UX não é muito boa, mas funciona.